# Why has the contract been renewed for another season when it has a low viewership?

Tags: revenge-tv

[Revenge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenge_%28TV_series%29) has been renewed for a third season. However, it had steadily dropping viewership with just 6 million viewers watching the season 2 finale. There have been shows which have been cancelled with a [much higher and stable viewership](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numb3rs#Production).

Why is this still on?

Comment: As this is a business question rather than film plot one I'm not sure you'll get an answer...

Comment: @Liath Is it off-topic?

Comment: I don't think so but I think it may be a hard one to answer if the studios have not given a reason

Comment: I'm guessing that any show that makes a profit would get renewed. That's one of the reasons why news shows and reality TV shows are so popular with networks - their cost is so low that they don't need that many viewers to make a profit (and probably why sf and fantasy die so quickly - special effects are expensive).

Answer (score 8):

Some viewers are more valuable to advertisers (and hence a TV network) than others ([source](http://www.dmn3.com/dmn3-blog/conventional-wisdom-of-advertising-demographics-no-longer-applies)):

> Conventional advertising logic is that the number of viewers of a television program within the 18-49 age range is more important than the total number of viewers. Television advertising rates are still, by and large, based on this premise.

Revenge is [popular with the 18-49 age range](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Revenge_%28TV_series%29#Ratings), so this is probably the reason for it being renewed.

Other possibly reasons for a show with low viewership being renewed are strong DVD sales (e.g. [Peep Show](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peep_Show_%28TV_series%29#Ratings)) or being popular overseas (Revenge is [broadcast in over 30 countries](http://whatafy.com/revenge-the-series.html)).

Comment: Researched answer with sources. Outstanding!